# Getting all the distinct words that follow after a specific string

Tags: java, arraylist, hashset

I want to know all the distinct words that follow after "apple". I am using a HashSet to get these words but I am running into an error.

This is the method that I am calling in main. I am supposed to be getting [banana, cherry] as the return value but I am only getting [banana].

```
ArrayList<String> test = new ArrayList<>();
        test.add("orange");
        test.add("apple");
        test.add("banana");
        test.add("cherry");
        System.out.println(test);
        System.out.println(problem1(test));

public static HashSet<String> problem1 (ArrayList<String> allWords){
        HashSet<String> words = new HashSet<>();
        String previousWord = "";
        
        for(String currentWord : allWords)
        {
            if(previousWord.equals("apple")) {
                words.add(currentWord);
                
            }
            previousWord = currentWord;
        }
        return words;
    }
```

Comment: 'running into an error', that's to vague. can you be more specific

Comment: Hey did you get a chance to see the rest of my question ?

Comment: Step through your program with the debugger.

Comment: Why do you think that you should get both banana and cherry? Only one of those follows **immediately** after apple (and that's banana). Cherry is immediately after banana, so it doesn't seem to fit your criterium.

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS thanks for the help ! I wrapped that line of code in an else block and I am getting the expected output. Is that a efficient practice or should I put the statement in the if block ?

Comment: @AbhiveerSharma: that doesn't really make much sense to me. What do you think the return value of [apple, foo, bar, baz, quux] should be?

Comment: Putting it in an `else` and `if` do different things... They mean the complete opposite.

Comment: @JoachimSauer I wanted to get all the words that follow apple. So, I am expecting the return value of [apple, foo, bar, baz, quux] to be [foo, bar, baz, quux]

Comment: @DavidLee Like having the line of code previousWord = currentWord inside the if block above rather than having it inside a separate else block would lead to different outcomes ?

Comment: @AbhiveerSharma: but that's not what you describe in your title. It explicitly says 'words that **immediately** follow "apple"'. So it seems you should have been a bit more diligent in constructing your question. If you don't ask for the right thing, it's easy to get the wrong answer.

Comment: @AbhiveerSharma Of course... If you don't put it inside the `if` then the **previousWord** will always be updated whereas if you put it in the `else` then it would only update if the **previousWord** does not equal "apple".

Comment: HashSet does not have any ordering, you would need to use LinkedHashSet

Comment: Also, you could use Java 8 Collections, stream().distinct() to maintain order and remove duplicates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This task can be resolved with the help of the following methods:

- [`List::indexOf`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#indexOf(java.lang.Object)) - to find the index of the desired string and increment it to skip the desired string
- [`List::subList`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#subList(int,int)) - get the sublist from the desired index

Also it may be better to get the result as a `LinkedHashSet` to maintain the order of the elements in the input list:

```java
public static Set<String> findWordsAfter(List<String> allWords, String afterMe) {
    
    return new LinkedHashSet<>(
        allWords.subList(allWords.indexOf(afterMe) + 1, allWords.size())
    );
}
```

Similarly, Stream API may be used to skip the words in the input list and collect the results into a set:

```java
public static Set<String> findWordsAfter2(List<String> allWords, String wordAfter) {  
    return allWords.stream()
            .skip(allWords.indexOf(wordAfter) + 1)
            .collect(Collectors.toCollection(LinkedHashSet::new));
}
```

Tests:

```java
List<String> words = Arrays.asList("orange", "apple", "banana", "cherry", "cherry");

List<String> lookFor = Arrays.asList("apple", "pear");

lookFor.forEach(wordAfter -> {
    System.out.printf("Getting words after '%s'%n", wordAfter);
    
    System.out.println("subList:     " + findWordsAfter(words, wordAfter));
    System.out.println("stream.skip: " + findWordsAfter2(words, wordAfter));
    
    System.out.println("----");
});
```

Output

```
Getting words after 'apple'
subList:     [banana, cherry]
stream.skip: [banana, cherry]
----
Getting words after 'pear'
subList:     [orange, apple, banana, cherry]
stream.skip: [orange, apple, banana, cherry]
----
```

Answer (score 0):

You can actually reduce your problem to the following steps:

1. Find the index of the keyword (here "apple")
2. Add everything from this index + 1 (next word) until the end of the input

```
public static Set<String> problem1 (List<String> allWords){
    HashSet<String> words = new HashSet<>();
    int startIndex = allWords.indexOf("apple");
    if (startIndex == -1) {
        return words; // No match
    }
    for (int i = startIndex + 1; i < allWords.size(); i++) {
        words.add(allWords.get(i));
    }
    return words;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

previousWord for "cherry" isn't "apple", so it's normal if the function didn't return "cherry"